# Loading only the function I need

Tags: javascript

Please do not be hard with me, i know it is basic, but..

I have a large file called `Firebase.js` , where i have many functions used to read/write from a server.

When I load a page i include this file using :

```
    <script src="../javascripts/Firebase.js"></script>
```

The thing is that this file is large, and in some pages i only need 1 function from it.

I can put all those functions in many files, and include a lot of files which seems like a mess.

**Questions**:

1. Does the server return the whole file on page request or only the relevant functions that this page is using?
2. On load, does the browser load/read all of it, or only functions used in the particiuar page ?
3. What is the proper way to reduce the loading time relate to this file ?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes. 3. Chop it up into smaller files. You may be able to use *tree shaking* in build tools such as Webpack, which will automatically (try to) eliminate unused functions.

Comment: How large is the file? Have you minified it for production? Do you use gzip? You could make it load only once with proper caching headers.

Comment: @deceze thanks very much. thanks Yury and Robby.  Using a class for each function will change anything here ?  so your advice is to create a file per function? and what if those functions share many other helper functions ? it will become a hair ball isn't it ? I am really curious - how such a thing is done by serious developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, browser will load the whole file.
2. Yes, browser will read and in all functions within Firebase.js
3. You need to split your file to menu small files.

Javascript is a dynamic programming language. Browser can't know about functions that will be loaded on a page.

Too you can minify and gzip file reduce file's size.

Answer (score 0):

On Firebase's [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize), you can find the following:

> To include only specific Firebase products (for example, Authentication and Cloud Firestore), add the following scripts to the bottom of your  tag

If you want to have the best performance possible, you'd need to specify page by page which js files you want to use.